# I need to access two values in one <option> element

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

Basically I have a `select menu` where they choose what seating they would like, These menus have values of the pricing connected to it. `eg value="100".`

But now I need to print the name of the seating(Balcony, levelOne, levelTwo, lowerArea) To a string which displays in a `html p` tag.

#### Here is my html:

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
      <label for="selectmenu" class="select">Preferred Seating:</label> <!-- Following drop down checkbox -->
      <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
        <option name="selectmenu" value="200" id="lowerArea" >Lower Area($200)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="150" selected="selected" id="levelOne">Level 1($150)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="100" id="levelTwo">Level 2($100)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="200" id="balcony">Balcony($200)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Below is the javascript, There are other values that are currently on a different page. Basically the cost variable will grab the element that is selected and multiply it by the number of tickets they have inputted. What I want to do is display the seating(Balconys, lowerArea etc..) **seating** variable that is inside the **OrderInput += ()**.

```
    cost = parseInt(document.getElementById('selectmenu').value,10) * numTickets;//This calculates the cost(selectMenu*numTickets)
    var Orderemail = document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').value;//This will grab the email value Inputed.

OrderInput +=("Your details are: <br />" + "Your E-mail address is: " + Orderemail + "<br />" + newsletter + "<br /> <br />" +
"You have the following tickets reserved: <br />" + numTickets +" on " + prefNight + " and your seating is :" +  seating + "<br /> <br />" +  "The total cost of your order will be: $" + cost); 
        document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = OrderInput;//This prints the users details to a html element.
            document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = '';//Removes error messages when everything is correct.
```

}

A quick rundown of what I would like to do:
I would like to print the names of the seating arrangements in the **seating** variable inside the **orderInput** variable. I just dont know how to do this as there is already a value on it. The value on it is valuable because I need it to get the price of the seating.
Thanks.

Comment: use $( "#selectmenu option:selected" ).attr('id') for get the selected value ID

Comment: @Manisha Patel he is not using jQuery.

Comment: But, but, [is there a world without jQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way is to just `split` the innerText:

```
var seating=document.getElementById('selectmenu').innerText.split("(")[0];
```

Better is to build your select from a prebuild array and use an ID. When the user selects something you search for the id:

```
var array=[{name:"Lower Area",price:100},{name:"Level 1",price:150}];
var select=document.getElementById('selectmenu');
for(var id=0;id<array.length;id++) {
   select.innerHtml+="<select value='"+id+"'>"+array[id].name+" ($"+array[id].value+")</select>";
}

//on change event:
var slectedId=document.getElementById('selectmenu').value;
var seating =array[slectedId].name;
var cost=array[slectedId].price*amount;
```

Why is the last version better? You can extend it easier. Imagine you have to add a discount. In your current solution you need to split a third time and it will get very messy. If you use a array you can easily extend this array and request the value by using the id `array[selectedId].discount` and calculate the total price.

**Edit for easier understanding**

If you have the following html:

```
  <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
    <option value="0">Lower Area ($200)</option>
    <option value="1">Level 1 ($150)</option>
  </select>
```

And the Javascript array:

```
var array=[{name:"Lower Area",price:100},{name:"Level 1",price:150}];
```

you can access the values by the `value` attribute of the `option` html tag on a change event:

```
document.getElementById('selectmenu').addEventListener("onchange",function() {
  var slectedId=document.getElementById('selectmenu').value;
  var seating =array[slectedId].name;
  var cost=array[slectedId].price*amount;
});
```

Why? Because this:

```
var array=[{name:"Lower Area",price:100},{name:"Level 1",price:150}];
```

Is equals to this:

```
var array=[];
array[0]={name:"Lower Area",price:100};
array[1]={name:"Level 1",price:150};
```

Comment: Your array seems the way to go but I don't really get how to do it? Could you maybe give a html example aswell with the array? I would appreciate that a lot! :). If not i'll try figure it out as I'm just a beginner in javscript !
Thanks again

Comment: I was wondering how it's possible to use the:var seating=document.getElementById('selectmenu').innerText.split("(")[0];